# Integrate$ \int x \cos(x) \sin(x)\; dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

> Integrate: $$\int x \cos(x) \sin(x) \;dx$$

I've been trying to integrate by parts, but I can't! I know there's a trigonometric function about $\cos (2x)$ but I don't know how to integrate that function with $\sin(x)$.

Comment: $\int \frac 12x \sin 2x dx$ as $\sin 2x=2\sin x\cos x$

Comment: Have you tried $u=x$, $dv=\sin x\cos xdx$? Note that $\sin x\cos x=\frac12\sin 2x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use integration by parts on $$ \int x\cos (x)\sin(x)\ dx $$  with

$$ u=x$$ and $$dv= \cos (x)\sin(x)\ dx $$

Then you will have $$du = dx $$ and $$ v=  (1/2)\sin ^2 x $$

You can finish the rest because you know how to integrate $(1/2)\sin ^2 x$

Answer (score 5):

Given $$\int x\cos (x)\sin(x)\ dx$$

Use the identity $\cos(x)\sin(x)=\dfrac{\sin(2x)}{2}$

Now $$\int x\ \dfrac{\sin(2x)}{2}\ dx=\dfrac12\int x\sin(2x)\ dx$$

Now use Integration By Parts $u=x$ and $v^{\prime}=\sin(2x)$

Can you continue from here?

Answer (score 1):

$\int x \cos(x) \sin(x) dx = \int x \frac{1}{2} \sin(2x) dx = \frac{1}{2}\int x \sin(2x)dx \\= \frac{1}{2}x[-\frac{1}{2}\cos(2x)]-\frac{1}{2}\int [-\frac{1}{2}\cos(2x)]dx + C \\=  -\frac{1}{4}x\cos(2x)+\frac{1}{8}\int \cos(2x)d(2x)+C\\ = -\frac{1}{4}x\cos(2x)+\frac{1}{8}\sin(2x)+C$

Comment: $\LaTeX \text{ Tip:}$ Use \sin x and \cos x to obtain $\sin x$ and $\cos x$

Comment: @Raptor Thanks for the tip. It has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways. Let us try by parts on $\cos x$:

$$I:=\int x\cos x\sin x\,dx=x\sin^2x-\int\sin x(x\cos x+\sin x)\,dx
=x\sin^2x-I-\int\sin^2x\,dx.$$

Now,

$$J:=\int\sin^2x\,dx=-\cos x\sin x+\int\cos^2x\,dx
=-\cos x\sin x-J+\int dx.$$

Grouping the results,

$$I=\frac{2x\sin^2x+\cos x\sin x-x}4.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int x\cos(x)\sin(x)dx$$
Integration by parts time!
$$dv=\cos(x)\sin(x)dx$$
$$v=\frac1{2}\sin^2(x)$$
and
$$u=x\\du=dx$$
Giving
$$I=\int udv=uv-\int vdu$$
$$I=\frac{x\sin^2(x)}{2}-\int\frac1{2}\sin^2(x)dx$$
Now we solve $$A=\int\frac1{2}\sin^2(x)dx$$
because $I=\frac{x}{2}\sin^2(x)-A$.

$$A=\int\frac1{2}\sin^2(x)dx$$
$$A=\frac1{2}\int\sin^2(x)dx$$
The sine reduction formula for positive whole powers $n$ gives 
$$\int\sin^n(x)dx=\frac{-\cos(x)\sin^{n-1}(x)}{n}+\frac{n-1}{n}\int\sin^{n-1}(x)dx$$
Applying it ($n=2$) gives
$$A=\frac1{2}\int\sin^2(x)dx=\frac{1}{2}\bigg(\frac{-\cos(x)\sin^{2-1}(x)}{2}+\frac{2-1}{2}\int\sin^{2-1}(x)dx\bigg)$$
$$A=\frac{1}{2}\bigg(\frac{-\cos(x)\sin(x)}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\int\sin(x)dx\bigg)$$
And from $\int\sin xdx=-\cos x$ we have 
$$A=\frac{-\cos(x)\sin(x)}{4}-\frac{1}{4}\cos(x)$$
$$A=\frac{-1}{4}(\cos(x)\sin(x)+\cos(x))$$
$$A=\frac{-\cos(x)}{4}(\sin(x)+1)$$
And from $I=\frac{x}{2}\sin^2(x)-A$, we have 
$$I=\frac{x}{2}\sin^2(x)+\frac{\cos(x)}{4}(\sin(x)+1)$$
And since we're done integrating, we add the constant of integration
$$I=\frac{x}{2}\sin^2(x)+\frac{\cos(x)}{4}(\sin(x)+1)+C$$

For future reference, [this site](https://www.integral-calculator.com/) is great for these sorts of integrals: it gives you detailed step-by-step solutions.